# How to get literal string value of Project Pre Build Event property

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, windows-installer, nuget

For my work I have to define a pre build event in a powershell script, which will be added to the target project that I install the NuGet package in. The script installs fine the first time, the pre build event is being added the right way like this:

```
xcopy $(SolutionDir)Some\Path $(ProjectDir)Some\Other\Path
```

When I uninstall and install my NuGet package again, the existing pre build events are being requested from the target project. The problem is that when an environment variable like $(ProjectDir) or $(SolutionDir) is being used in the pre build event, my powershell script gets the value that is associated with the variable. Like so:

```
c:\Path\To\Solution\Dir
```

or:

```
C:\Path\To\Project\Dir
```

But I want it to give me the string with the env variables in it.
How can I get the literal value from the pre build events in powershell?

Tim

UPDATE::

I have done a little more research and concluded that the environment variables in the build events won't be replaced UNLESS it is a Windows Installer project.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get literal string value of Project Pre Build Event property

AFAIK, you can't get literal string value of Project Pre Build Event property. Because **Macros are expanded by the** [Preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), which happens even before the code is compiled. It is a purely textual replacement.

Comment: Is there another way where I can set the pre build event of a project, and when someone else has my code, he can still build the project with the same pre build event?

Comment: @iPhantomGuy, The key to this problem is not where you can set the pre build event of a project, just because you are using the environment variables "$(ProjectDir)","$(SolutionDir)" in the build event, however, those variables are regarded as the default variable name of Macros in the build event. So to resolve this issue, you should change those environment variables with another ID, such as  "$(PathForProjectDir)".

Comment: where do i define that variable then? And will it still work if someone else installs my package and then tries to build it without doing anything else?